# Irrational equation $\sqrt{9-4x}=p-2x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> The equation
>   $$\sqrt{9-4x}=p-2x$$
>   has exactly 2 real and different solutions only if parameter $p$ belongs to which set?

So what I see here, to have the solutions be real in the first place,

$9-4x\ge0$

So $-4x\ge-9 \Rightarrow x\le{9\over4}$

$x\in\left(-\infty,{9\over4}\right]$

From here I quadrate both sides so I get 2 different possibilities:

**1.** For $p\ge2x$:

$9-4x=p^2-4x+4x^2\\9-4x-p^2+4x-4x^2=0\\-4x^2-p^2+9=0$

And for this to have 2 real and different solutions, $D>0$

$-4(-4)(-p^2+9)>0\\16(-p^2+9)>0\\-16p^2+144>0\\-16p^2>-144\\p^2<9\\|p|<3 \Rightarrow p\in(-3,3)$

**2.** For $p<2x:$

$9-4x=-p^2+4x-4x^2\\9-4x+p^2+4x^2-4x=0\\4x^2-8x+p^2+9=0$

Again $D>0$

$(-8)^2-4\cdot4(p^2+9)>0\\64-16p^2-144>0\\p^2<-5\\p\notin\Bbb R$

The problem here is I don't know how to use $x\in\left(-\infty,{9\over4}\right]$ in both cases, so I don't exactly know the solution to this problem. From the textbook I got this question from the result  is $p\in\left[{9\over2},5\right)$

Comment: 1) The casework comes upon taking square roots, not in squaring. In particular, $(p-2x)^2=p^2-4x+4x^2$ regardless of whether $p-2x$ is positive or negative. 2) The quantity $\sqrt{9-4x}$, being the principal root, is assumed to be positive.

Comment: @Semiclassical But for it to be real, shouldn't it always be positive when squared?

Comment: Yes, and $p^2-4x+4x^2$ is nonnegative whenever $x,p$ are real quantities. There's no contradiction there.

Comment: @Semiclassical Okay, so that makes only my first case valid, but again, how do I connect the result I got from there with the $x$ set I got?

Comment: Oh, a big typo I missed (and accidentally reproduced): $(p-2x)^2=p^2-4xp+4x^2$, not $p^2-4x+4x^2$

Comment: @Semiclassical Oh wow, I didn't spot that either, I'll try doing it again while keeping in mind what you said

Comment: @Semiclassical Okay, so I got $p<5$, which I see is in the solution $p\in[{9\over2},5)$. But where did they get the $9\over2$ from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already pointed out in a comment, $(p-2x)^2 = p^2-4px+4x^2$, which results in
$$4x^2 - 4(p-1)x+(p^2-9) = 0,$$
or
$$x = \frac{(p-1)\pm\sqrt{10-2p}}{2}.$$
For two real distinct roots, $10-2p > 0 \implies \color{red}{p < 5}$.

Also, $p \ge 2x$ implies $$(p-1)\pm\sqrt{10-2p} \le p \implies \sqrt{10-2p}\le 1 \implies \color{red}{p \ge \frac{9}{2}}.$$

Note that

Comment: Finally someone answered! So the $p\ge 2x$ was needed after all? I still don't understand why I didn't do the case where $p\le 2x$, could you clear that up in a comment here?

Comment: @Aleksa The square root, $\sqrt{9-4x}$, is always non-negative. That is why $p-2x \ge 0$. For example, $\sqrt{9-4x}=-3$ does not have a real solution.